# Can I use an array which contains UIImage objects as index titles in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, indexing, uiimage

I want to show some images instead of showing A-Z letters as index in UITableView. From Apple's documentation,

[image]

Also,

- I'm having grouped table instead of a plain one. Will Apple reject my app because of this?
- Is there any way to return a NSArray that contains a set of UIImages? I tried but it throws error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `return` value for `sectionIndexTlesForTableView` should be an `array` of `strings`.

I think images instead of strings `not` `possible`.

Comment: So, should I create a index like custom view?

Answer (score 0):

Using grouped style, the documentation is clear, you can't implement that method (sectionIndexTitlesForTableView)

Comment: You're answering the wrong question. This is about the index letters shown down the right side of the table view.

Comment: Still not correct. How can adding an image to the cell work in place of the index letters down the side?